# my grid view does not refresh after sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid view in my project and wrote codes for converting dates in my grid view to a Persian calendar dates

For the first time when grid view appear all of the data my dates are in Persian format correctly but if I press the button for sorting that it appear dates in the english format again

how should I keep Persian format dates after sorting?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
public partial class dr_report : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
          GridView2.Visible = false;
          string userinput = "";
          int c = GridView1.Rows.Count;
          for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
          {
              userinput = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text;
              System.DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(userinput);
              System.Globalization.PersianCalendar p = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();

              int year = p.GetYear(date);
              int month = p.GetMonth(date);
              int day = p.GetDayOfMonth(date);
              System.DateTime currentDate = new System.DateTime(year, month, 1);
              currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(day - 1);

              GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text = currentDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");


           }
         }
      }




     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       GridView1.Visible = false;
       GridView2.Visible = true;
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
       con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=daymond;Integrated Security=True";
       SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
       SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand();
       SqlDataAdapter dat = new SqlDataAdapter();
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       com.Connection = con;
       con.Open();

       string query = "select [usercustomer], [uservisitor], [idcustomer], [takhasos], [date] from [customer] where idcustomer = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
       com.CommandText = query;
       com.Connection = con;
       com1.CommandText = "Delete from [customer] where [idcustomer]=1255";
       dat.DeleteCommand =com1;
       dat.SelectCommand = com;
       dat.Fill(dt);
       GridView2.DataSource = dt;
       GridView2.DataBind();
     }



   protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=daymond;Initial Catalog=daymond;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

    Session.Remove("users");
    Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
   }




  protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

  }
 }
```

Comment: Ithink you need to check IsPostback event ? can you show full code means page load event and sort button click event

Comment: It's an automatic button for sorting  in grid view
I already sent the page load code

Comment: Do you written this code inside page_load event without checking IsPostback condition true or false

Comment: @MangeshAuti Yes, I entered this code into the page-load and IsPostback is true

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  if (!this.IsPostBack)
  {
   //your code 
  }
    }

Comment: is your code in above format

Comment: @MangeshAuti yes

Comment: so  remove if(!this.IsPostBack)  condition means dont check whether it postback or not

Comment: @MangeshAuti
 Does not convert

Comment: can you show your full code so try to reproduce it on my setup

Comment: Can you move your code into the RowCreated event method and modify each row as its created?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @MangeshAuti I can't send full code because of limitation in these messages

Comment: you update your code in question itself

Comment: @MangeshAuti
Full code placed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd move your code to the RowCreated event.

```
void GridView1_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {


    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
    string userInput = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;
    System.DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(userInput);
    System.Globalization.PersianCalendar p = newSystem.Globalization.PersianCalendar(); 

    int year = p.GetYear(date);
    int month = p.GetMonth(date);
    int day = p.GetDayOfMonth(date);
    System.DateTime currentDate = new System.DateTime(year, month, 1);
    currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(day - 1);
    e.Row.Cells[4].Text = currentDate.ToString();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to store the sortExpression into a viewstate and sort the datasource before binding to gridview

```
DataView dv = ds.Tables["Test"].DefaultView;

    // Set the sort column and sort order.
    dv.Sort = ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString(); 

    // Bind the GridView control.
    GridView1.DataSource = dv;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

[Check this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1896225.aspx?Problem%20in%20updating%20gridview%20after%20sorting)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Page_Load` event use `OnSaveStateComplete` event of page, it fires at the end of the page life cycle. More Info [Page_Cycle in asp.net](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/page-life-cycle-with-examples-in-Asp-Net/)

So when Grid view bind with source and sort the column then you can apply your logic to change the date format

```
 protected override void OnSaveStateComplete(EventArgs e)
        {
            string userinput = "";
            int c = GridView1.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                userinput = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text;


                System.DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(userinput);
                System.Globalization.PersianCalendar p = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();

                int year = p.GetYear(date);
                int month = p.GetMonth(date);
                int day = p.GetDayOfMonth(date);
                System.DateTime currentDate = new System.DateTime(year, month, 1);
                currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(day - 1);

                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text = currentDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            }
        }
```

Comment: Glad to help you !!

Comment: We have website that everybody can add a record witch includes date column everytime the add a record to database a date will save in date column and when they want to see them in a gridview, it will be convert in persian calendar format

The problem is that some specific dates can not convert.for example if we want to convert date 1398/2/30 or 1398/2/31  to Gregorian date, It will give an error